# Find all string split combinations

Tags: python, arrays, string, recursion

I'm looking for a way to get all the string splits combinations from a sentence. 
For example, for the input sentance :

> "I am eating pizza"

I would like to get this output :

```
[["I", "am", "eating", "pizza"],
["I", "am eating", "pizza"],
["I", "am", "eating pizza"],
["I", "am eating pizza"],
["I am", "eating", "pizza"],
["I am", "eating pizza"],
["I am eating", "pizza"],
["I am eating pizza"]]
```

I can't find the recursive way of doing this ! Do you have any idea ? 
This is NOT a duplicate : I am not looking for the whole combinations, only ordered items and always the whole words. Can't find my answer from the alleged duplicate.

Comment: There are 2^n results, n being the number of places where a split can occur.  You can see it as a binary number, each 1 means split here, each 0 means don't split here.  Now you only have to iterate and interpret the digits.

Comment: First split all tokens based on whitespace characters, then build all possible combinations.

Comment: @Alfe I like your solution ! will try that, thanks

Comment: How is the alleged duplicate a duplicate of this question??  The other ticket is about ordered combinations, this is about all possible splits.  The other answer allows e. g. the result `"I"` while this question does not.  Either I'm too stupid to see the obvious equality of the two questions or they simply aren't alike, in which case I'd like to ask all the duplicate-voters to be more thorough when giving such a vote.

Comment: @Alfe totally agree, I don't really understand why it was voted as a duplicate

Comment: Anyway, thank you @Alfe your solution worked ! I used itertools.product to find all combinations of (0,1) and then I splitted my string whenever I had a 1.

Comment: Yeah, well, but there's a nicer way using recursion, accomplishing the same:  `def f(q):`, `→if len(q) > 1:`, `→→for sub in f(q[1:]):`, `→→→yield [ ' '.join([ q[0], sub[0] ]) ] + sub[1:]`, `→→→yield [ q[0] ] + sub`, `→else:`, `→→yield q`.  If you do that and call `list(f("I am eating pizza".split()))` you will get `[['I am eating pizza'], ['I', 'am eating pizza'], ['I am', 'eating pizza'], ['I', 'am', 'eating pizza'], ['I am eating', 'pizza'], ['I', 'am eating', 'pizza'], ['I am', 'eating', 'pizza'], ['I', 'am', 'eating', 'pizza']]`

Comment: @Alfe That's exactly what I was looking for. I was kinda close :D thanks

Comment: Then you should have shown your trials ;-)  (next time!)

Comment: @Alfe: I think that either you or Mohamed should post a answer with that. You proposed a simple yet valid algorithm and even an implementation. Questions without answers are sad...

Comment: @serge-ballesta I couldn't post an answer because the Q was closed as duplicate (wrongly).  Of course I would have.  But giving the solution was more important, so I at least gave it in the comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**subdivide and recur**

Here's a way you can do it using a recursive function – and how I approached the design:

- Scan a string `s` using an index `i`
- If the index goes out of bounds, return the base result, `[[s]]`, otherwise...
- If a `" "` is found at the index, subdivide the problem into two parts *A* and *B* and merge their results, otherwise advance to the next index.
- Part A: split on this space, prepend word before it to each item in the recursive result.
- Part B: do *not* split on this space, advance to the next index

```
# split :: String -> [[String]]
def split (s, i = 0):
  if len(s) == i:
    return [[s]]
  elif s[i] == " ":
           # Part A                                     # Part B
    return [[s[0:i]] + acc for acc in split(s[i + 1:])] + split(s, i + 1)
  else:
    return split(s, i + 1)

print(split("i am eating pizza"))

# [ ['i', 'am', 'eating', 'pizza'], 
# , ['i', 'am', 'eating pizza']
# , ['i', 'am eating', 'pizza']
# , ['i', 'am eating pizza']
# , ['i am', 'eating', 'pizza']
# , ['i am', 'eating pizza']
# , ['i am eating', 'pizza']
# , ['i am eating pizza']
# ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Alfe with his hint with the 2^n combinations.

This is some code, corresponding to his idea.

```
import itertools
input_string = "I am eating pizza"
split_string = input_string.split(' ')
lst = list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=len(split_string) - 1))

res = [] 
for entry in lst:
    round_output = []
    current = split_string[0]
    for i in range(len(entry)):
        if entry[i] == 1:
            current += ' ' + split_string[i+1]
        else:    
            round_output.append(current)
            current = split_string[i+1]
    round_output.append(current)
    res.append(round_output)
```